# Adding custom info before message is sent to DLQ in Spring Cloud Streams

Tags: spring, spring-cloud-stream, spring-retry

I'm using Spring Cloud Streams and the default Spring Retry mechanism only by using properties. It works well, messages are retried, then go to DLQ... All great so far. Now comes the question...

I need to add some custom info in the message before it departs from my service to the DLQ. They are simple enough, and would help me identify the failed messages without touching a generic payload.

Possibly I could add custom headers or wrap it in a known model, where I could retrieve the info I need - either way I would need to intercept/modify the message.

What is the simplest way to do it, without much cost? I mean, we are using simply configuration to do the retries, so by 'cost' I mean to swap the config with something else. Thanks anyway!

Comment: Which binder are you using (e.g. RabbitMQ or Kafka)?

Comment: Hi @GaryRussell - using Kafka.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the Kafka binder you can add a `ProducerInterceptor` to the kafka producer configuration `interceptor.classes`.

```
/**
 * This is called from {@link org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer#send(ProducerRecord)} and
 * {@link org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer#send(ProducerRecord, Callback)} methods, before key and value
 * get serialized and partition is assigned (if partition is not specified in ProducerRecord).
 * <p>
 * This method is allowed to modify the record, in which case, the new record will be returned. The implication of modifying
 * key/value is that partition assignment (if not specified in ProducerRecord) will be done based on modified key/value,
 * not key/value from the client. Consequently, key and value transformation done in onSend() needs to be consistent:
 * same key and value should mutate to the same (modified) key and value. Otherwise, log compaction would not work
 * as expected.
 * <p>
 * Similarly, it is up to interceptor implementation to ensure that correct topic/partition is returned in ProducerRecord.
 * Most often, it should be the same topic/partition from 'record'.
 * <p>
 * Any exception thrown by this method will be caught by the caller and logged, but not propagated further.
 * <p>
 * Since the producer may run multiple interceptors, a particular interceptor's onSend() callback will be called in the order
 * specified by {@link org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.ProducerConfig#INTERCEPTOR_CLASSES_CONFIG}. The first interceptor
 * in the list gets the record passed from the client, the following interceptor will be passed the record returned by the
 * previous interceptor, and so on. Since interceptors are allowed to modify records, interceptors may potentially get
 * the record already modified by other interceptors. However, building a pipeline of mutable interceptors that depend on the output
 * of the previous interceptor is discouraged, because of potential side-effects caused by interceptors potentially failing to
 * modify the record and throwing an exception. If one of the interceptors in the list throws an exception from onSend(), the exception
 * is caught, logged, and the next interceptor is called with the record returned by the last successful interceptor in the list,
 * or otherwise the client.
 *
 * @param record the record from client or the record returned by the previous interceptor in the chain of interceptors.
 * @return producer record to send to topic/partition
 */
public ProducerRecord<K, V> onSend(ProducerRecord<K, V> record);
```

The producer record contains the destination topic name; you can add/remove headers there.

There's currently not a similar hook for the RabbitMQ binder. If you are using that binder, open new feature issue on GitHub against the binder.

Comment: Thanks @GaryRussell - using kafka here. Wondering if I have to use something to intercept the message. On a specific error (or after the retries), they go the a DLQ directly

Comment: As I explained above, you can use a `ProducerInterceptor`; what's not clear? I am not sure what more you need.